# Steam launches using terminal, but not with launcher icon Ubuntu 21.10 / Nvidia Drivers-495

Tags: nvidia, launcher, steam

I've come across something interesting with the Steam Launcher.

### The sytem:

System is a ThinkPad P50 with an Nvidia Quadro M1000M.
It's is Ubuntu 21.10 - fresh install.
Nvidia Drivers 495.

Steam launcher is installed from the Ubuntu Software app.

Nvidia is set to dedicated graphics only. (In the nvidia settings program it's set to "Nvidia", as oppsed to "Nvidia On demand" or "Intel")

### The issue:

When I click on the steam icon, it will sometimes briefly pop up the little updater window, and then nothing will happen further. `ps` shows a defunct steam process.

```
ps aux | grep steam
user       17368  0.0  0.0  18840  3816 ?        S    09:24   0:00 bash /home/arbs/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh -nominidumps -nobreakpad
user       17512  4.3  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   09:24   0:00 [steam] <defunct>
```

This defunct process will just sit there until I kill it.

### The weird part:

If I just launch steam using the terminal, by running `steam`, it works fine! This is strange, because this is exactly what the steam.desktop file executes when you click on the desktop icon

Any ideas on how to get the icon working?
Thanks!

Comment: I got the exact same error, no idea why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue after upgrading my laptop to Ubuntu 21.04 and upgrading my Nvidia drivers to version 495. Running it from the terminal also worked.

I looked at my `/var/log/syslog` file and found the following after launching Steam from the desktop.

```
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306442] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306447] kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/drm/drm_gem.c:154!
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306452] invalid opcode: 0000 [#12] SMP NOPTI
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306454] CPU: 11 PID: 34354 Comm: steam Tainted: P      D    OE     5.11.0-41-generic #45-Ubuntu
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306456] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. TUF Gaming FA706IU_TUF706IU/FA706IU, BIOS FA706IU.311 09/11/2020
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306457] RIP: 0010:drm_gem_private_object_init+0x89/0x90 [drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306476] Code: c7 83 d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 83 e7 f8 29 fb 8d 8b d8 00 00 00 c1 e9 03 f3 48 ab 5b 41 5c 5d c3 4c 89 a3 f8 00 00 00 eb c7 <0f> 0b 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 54 49 89 d4 53
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306477] RSP: 0018:ffffacb107127cf0 EFLAGS: 00210206
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306479] RAX: ffff9b58986d3370 RBX: ffff9b58986d3360 RCX: 0000000000000200
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306480] RDX: 0000000000000200 RSI: ffff9b58986d3200 RDI: ffff9b5800a90000
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306481] RBP: ffffacb107127d18 R08: ffff9b58966fc088 R09: ffff9b58966fc088
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306482] R10: ffff9b580d564008 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9b58986d3200
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306483] R13: 0000000000000200 R14: ffff9b5800a90000 R15: ffff9b58aff82200
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306484] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9b5b1f8c0000(0063) knlGS:00000000f77e3740
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306485] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306487] CR2: 00000000572a3000 CR3: 00000001929c2000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306488] Call Trace:
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306490]  ? nv_drm_gem_object_init+0x60/0x70 [nvidia_drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306494]  nv_drm_gem_import_nvkms_memory_ioctl+0xb9/0x130 [nvidia_drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306496]  ? nv_drm_dumb_create+0x1e0/0x1e0 [nvidia_drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306499]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306513]  drm_ioctl+0x253/0x410 [drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306526]  ? nv_drm_dumb_create+0x1e0/0x1e0 [nvidia_drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306529]  ? nvidia_ioctl+0x3a7/0x8e0 [nvidia]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306712]  drm_compat_ioctl+0xdf/0xf0 [drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306729]  __do_compat_sys_ioctl+0x140/0x160
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306733]  __ia32_compat_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306735]  __do_fast_syscall_32+0x65/0xa0
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306738]  do_fast_syscall_32+0x34/0x80
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306739]  entry_SYSCALL_compat_after_hwframe+0x45/0x4d
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306742] RIP: 0023:0xf7f15549
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306743] Code: 03 74 c0 01 10 05 03 74 b8 01 10 06 03 74 b4 01 10 07 03 74 b0 01 10 08 03 74 d8 01 00 00 00 00 00 51 52 55 89 cd 0f 05 cd 80 <5d> 5a 59 c3 90 90 90 90 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306745] RSP: 002b:00000000ffe9d548 EFLAGS: 00200296 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000036
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306746] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000011 RCX: 00000000c0206441
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306747] RDX: 00000000ffe9d5d4 RSI: 000000005727a7b0 RDI: 00000000ffe9d5a0
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306748] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306749] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306749] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306751] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_counter nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bridge stp snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer nls_utf8 appletalk psnap llc cifs cmac fscache overlay libdes algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nvidia_uvm(POE) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) amdgpu snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec kvm_amd snd_hda_core soundwire_bus snd_soc_core kvm rtw88_8822ce snd_usb_audio rtw88_8822c snd_compress ac97_bus rtw88_pci snd_usbmidi_lib snd_pcm_dmaengine iommu_v2 snd_hwdep rtw88_core gpu_sched crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_pcm nls_iso8859_1 ttm aesni_intel btusb snd_seq_midi btrtl
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306780]  uvcvideo crypto_simd mac80211 btbcm snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_vmalloc btintel videobuf2_memops cryptd videobuf2_v4l2 glue_helper snd_rawmidi bluetooth videobuf2_common drm_kms_helper snd_seq rapl videodev input_leds snd_seq_device cec snd_timer serio_raw hid_multitouch rc_core joydev i2c_algo_bit asus_nb_wmi ecdh_generic fb_sys_fops mc efi_pstore snd_rn_pci_acp3x ecc wmi_bmof syscopyarea cfg80211 k10temp snd snd_pci_acp3x sysfillrect ccp ucsi_ccg sysimgblt soundcore libarc4 ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec asus_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap r8169 nvme crc32_pclmul ahci i2c_hid xhci_pci nvme_core i2c_piix4 libahci realtek xhci_pci_renesas i2c_nvidia_gpu wmi video hid
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.306812] ---[ end trace 6fb93b3dd8673b0d ]---
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334017] RIP: 0010:drm_gem_private_object_init+0x89/0x90 [drm]
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334038] Code: c7 83 d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 83 e7 f8 29 fb 8d 8b d8 00 00 00 c1 e9 03 f3 48 ab 5b 41 5c 5d c3 4c 89 a3 f8 00 00 00 eb c7 <0f> 0b 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 54 49 89 d4 53
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334040] RSP: 0018:ffffacb10170fcf0 EFLAGS: 00210206
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334042] RAX: ffff9b5872128970 RBX: ffff9b5872128960 RCX: 0000000000000200
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334043] RDX: 0000000000000200 RSI: ffff9b5872128800 RDI: ffff9b5800a90000
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334044] RBP: ffffacb10170fd18 R08: ffff9b580bc44a08 R09: ffff9b580bc44a08
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334045] R10: ffff9b580d564008 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9b5872128800
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334046] R13: 0000000000000200 R14: ffff9b5800a90000 R15: ffff9b5876eeb600
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334047] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9b5b1f8c0000(0063) knlGS:00000000f77e3740
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334048] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  9 12:05:18 cdeacon-bigmode kernel: [ 3212.334050] CR2: 00000000572a3000 CR3: 00000001929c2000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
```

I believe my issue was due to GNOME and the desktop icon using the dedicated GPU from Nvidia while there appears to be some sort of bug within the driver at the moment. Therefore, you will need to launch Steam while using integrated graphics until Nvidia corrects this issue to my understanding.

Modifying the desktop icon which was located in `/usr/share/applications/steam.desktop` for me (you may also copy this to `~/.local/share/applications` if you want to modify it under your home directory) and setting the following has fixed the issue for me:

```
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=false # This probably had no effect since I'm running GNOME, but just set it in-case.
```

These are set to true by default.

I also had to reboot in order for this change to take effect. I did try clearing the icon cache via the following, but for some reason those commands had no effect.

```bsh
# Attempted Solution #1
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/applications/*

# Attempted Solution #2
sudo touch /usr/share/icons/hicolor ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
```

I hope the above helps!

Comment: Hey, this worked, but only after the "reboot" part. Pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too! In my case I think it had to do with me switching external docks, which also switched between what GPU was being used (integrated vs dedicated) which somehow messed stuff up. Changing this config setting in the shortcut probably fixed that.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me after a reboot on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Funny enough though, when I copied this .desktop file to my actual desktop, it worked with no hiccups. But it was broken when I tried to launch it from the applications page.